# Regularity of solution to Laplacian equation with Neumann data on Lipschitz domain

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, harmonic-analysis, elliptic-pde, harmonic-functions

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded Lipschitz domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ be a weak solution to
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u=0 \quad &\mbox{in $\Omega$}\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}=g\quad &\mbox{on $\partial \Omega$},
\end{cases}
\end{equation}where $g \in L^{\infty}(\partial \Omega)$ satisfies
$$\int_{\partial \Omega}g \, d\sigma=0.$$

My question is that, how much regularity can we say on $u$? Does $u$ belong to $C^{\alpha}(\overline{\Omega})$ for some $\alpha \in (0,1)$?

I cannot seem to find a suitable reference. Any help would be really appreciated!

---

Update: I have found two relavent references:

[1] Bjorn E. J. Dahlberg and Carlos E. Kenig. Hardy Spaces and the Neumann Problem in Lp for Laplace's Equation in Lipschitz Domains. Annals of Mathematics , May, 1987, Second Series, Vol. 125, No. 3.

[2] E.B. Fabes, M. Jodeit and N.M. Rivière. Potential techniques for boundary value problems on $C^1$-domains. Acta Math. 141, 165–186 (1978).

The first paper proves that if $\Omega$ is a bounded Lipschitz domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ for some $2<p<2+\epsilon$. Hence $u$ belongs to some Holder space when $n=2$. Of course, in the $W^{1,p}$ estimate, $2+\epsilon$ is optimal, since one can construct a counter example by considering a two-dimensional cone-domains suggested by @Math604. I would like to know whether Holder regularity is true for $n \ge 3$ and small $\alpha$. If not, can we prove continuity of solutions up to the boundary?

The second paper proves that if $\Omega$ is a bounded $C^1$ domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $u$ must be in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ for any $1<p<\infty$. Hence $u$ must be in $C^{\alpha}(\overline{\Omega})$ for any $0<\alpha<1$.

Comment: maybe its work looking at the problem on a two dimensional cone near the vertex...this might give you some idea's on what to expect.

Comment: @Math604, I'm sure more general situation has been done in past literature, but I just cannot find a suitable reference, which is exactly what I have been looking for.

Comment: this may be (or may not be) the standard reference for this kind of stuff...Elliptic Problems in Nonsmooth Domains
Book by P. Grisvard ...   but it might be stated in such generality that it might be hard to read.   THere are people on Mathoverflow who will know the answer of the top of their head

Comment: a quick google gave this also (but here the coefficients are just measurable and bounded and hence probably in your case you can do much better...  but the `angle' at the boundary will matter for optimal results)  https://arxiv.org/pdf/0906.5285.pdf

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/312467/global-regularity-for-neumann-problem?rq=1